# Can block devices behave like character devices?

Tags: drivers

I do not know how I can explain this, but I have read something like that and right now I cannot find it:

> Block devices are the devices with which we can communicate by sending
>   blocks of data. However, we can also read or write arbitrary size of
>   data to these devices. This is not about the devices, actually, the
>   thing that provides this feature is the device driver controlling that
>   device.`

I think that the what that passage tries to say is that a block device cannot behave like a character device, but we can assume that it behaves like that. The device driver which controls that block device can provide a flexibility for us.

Is this possible ?

Edited:

As I guess, Linux block device drivers provide some features for the users so that they can use those devices like a character device. It is a privilege of device drivers of block devices.

Comment: Please do not post same question twice: https://askubuntu.com/q/1094220/295286 Editing original question would be sufficient

Comment: What are you trying to do with block device?  Block devices have the concept of address, and character devices do not.